# 'i have never made' in latin

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, latin-to-english-translation, sentence-translation

I've tried to search for this phrase, but I haven't found an answer. I looked it up on google translate and it says 'nunquam fecit.' I don't think it's correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Almost correct. The most common spelling of "never" in Latin is `numquam`.

`Fecit` is the third-person, to get the first person just drop that t: `feci`

Together you get: **`Numquam feci.`**

Now, this corresponds to the act of making something. If you had a fuller sentence, we would be able to tell you if this is the correct idiom to use. Remember that languages are never a simple 1-to-1 correspondence.

Comment: ah ok, thanks. the full sentence is ' I have never made a worse journey than this.' does this change anything?

Comment: The verb *facio* basically means to make something physical. To "make a journey" = to "go on a journey" and the verb would be *ire.*

Comment: *Iter facere*, "to make a journey", is a common enough idiom in Latin

Comment: @jonathan Yes, what Figulus said is correct. So *iter numquam feci*, "never have I made a journey." Cf. Caesar's, *sine ullo maleficio iter per provinciam facere*, :to make a journey throughout the province without [committing] any crime" (*BG* 1.7).